# Proving that a collection of all cofinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ is a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\mathbb{N}$, and let $\mathcal{T}$ be the collection consisting of the empty set and all sets $U\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{N}-U$ is finite. Prove that $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $\mathbb{N}$.

my proof so far:

By definition $\emptyset\in \mathcal{T}$. Then considering $\mathbb{N}-\mathbb{N}=\emptyset$ and the empty set is finite. Thus $\mathbb{N}\in \mathcal{T}$.

Now let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection in $\mathcal{T}$. If $\mathcal{C}$ contains $\mathbb{N}$ then the union of $\mathcal{C}$ is $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\in \mathcal{T}$. If $\mathcal{C}$ contains only the $\emptyset$ then the union is just the empty set and $\emptyset\in\mathcal{T}$. Then there exists $U\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $\mathbb{N}-U$ is finite. That is $U$ is infinite. Thus the union of $\mathcal{C}$ is infinite. Thus the union of $\mathcal{C}\in\mathcal{T}$.

Finally let $U_1,U_2\in\mathcal{T}$. If $U_1=\emptyset$ or $U_2=\emptyset$ then $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset\in\mathcal{T}$. If $U_1=\mathbb{N}$ then $U_1\cap U_2=U_2\in\mathcal{T}$. Also if $U_2=\mathbb{N}$ then $U_1\cap U_2=U_1\in\mathcal{T}$.

Now I am not sure how to show that $U_1\cap U_2\cap\dots \cap U_n\in \mathcal{T}$. Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't really shown that the complement of the union of $\cal C$ is finite (i.e. the union is "cofinite"). To show that $\cal T$ is closed under $\cap$, it's not necessary to consider the cases where some $U_i = \Bbb N$ as these are cofinite. Hint: where $X'=\Bbb N\setminus X$, $$(U\cap V)' = U'\cup V', \quad\text{ and }\quad (\bigcup_i U_i)' = \bigcap_i U'_i.$$

Comment: BTW it is called [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinite_topology) or finite complement topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $U_1, . . . , U_n\in\mathcal{T}$. We want to show that $U_1\cap . . . \cap U_n\in\mathcal{T}$. Let $C_i$ be the complement of $U_i$ ($1\le i\le n$).

- Since each $U_i$ is in $\mathcal{T}$, how big is each $C_i$?
- OK, so how big is their union $C_1\cup . . . \cup C_n$?
- What is the complement of $U_1\cap . . . \cap U_n$?
- So . . . ?